# Unable to append child elements to parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I have following code which does not work as expected:

```
$.each(results, function(idx, val) {
    $('<div>')
    .addClass('gmap-item')
    .attr('data-place-id', val.place_id)
    .append($('<span>').addClass('gmap-icon').addClass('gmap-icon-marker'))
    .append($('<span>').addClass('gmap-item-query').text(val.name))
    .text(val.formatted_address).appendTo(res);
}
```

basically, the two inner span tags do not get created/appended. I have no idea why. I had to replace it with the following:

```
res.append(
'<div class="gmap-item" data-place-id=\"' + val.place_id + '\">' +
'<span class="gmap-icon gmap-icon-marker"></span>' + 
'<span class="gmap-item-query">' + val.name + '</span>' +
val.formatted_address + '</div>');
```

which is ugly but it works. Any ideas why the proper way does not work?
Thanks for all answers!

Comment: What are `results` and `res`?

Comment: Try ```.append($('<span></span>'))```

Comment: Correct answer was given by @Knelis. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling `.append()` twice, you then call `.text()` which resets the contents of the `div`.

In this case you can use `.append()` also to add text, so do this:

```
$.each(results, function(idx, val) {
    $('<div>')
    .addClass('gmap-item')
    .attr('data-place-id', val.place_id)
    .append($('<span>').addClass('gmap-icon').addClass('gmap-icon-marker'))
    .append($('<span>').addClass('gmap-item-query').text(val.name))
    .append(val.formatted_address).appendTo(res);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for this, much appreciated.